# Does $(Tf)(x):=\int f(x+y)\:\mu({\rm d}y)$ vanish at infinity, if $f$ does?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a locally compact normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $$(Tf)(x):=\int f(x+y)\:\mu({\rm d}y)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E$$ for bounded Borel measurable $f:E\to\mathbb R$.

> Are we able to show that if$^1$ $f\in C_0(E)$, then $Tf\in C_0(E)$?

Note that every function in $C_0(E)$ is uniformly continuous and it is easy to show that $Tg$ is uniformly continuous for every bounded uniformly continuous $g:E\to\mathbb R$.

So, we only need to show that $\{|Tf|\ge\varepsilon\}$ is compact for every $\varepsilon>0$. Can we do that?

I'm not sure whether the local compactness assumption already implies that $E$ is finite-dimensional. However, if $X$ is a finite-dimensional normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, then for every function $g\in C(X)$, it obviously holds $$g(x)\xrightarrow{\|x\|_X\to\infty}0\tag1.$$ $(1)$ should be easier to check, but even in the finite-dimensional case I'm not sure whether $(1)$ is even a sufficient condition for a continuous $g$ to belong to $C_0(X)$.

---

If $X$ is a locally compact topological space, $f\in C(X)$ is the set of continuous functions $X\to\mathbb R$ such that $\{|f|\ge\varepsilon\}$ is compact for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: Can you do it it $\mu$ has compact support? Also: Condition (1) is equivalent to having $g \in C_0$. Try to prove this.

Comment: Locally compact Hausdorff topological vector spaces are indeed finite dimensional. This is certainly in Rudin's book *Functional Analysis*.